# importing api into google sheets

Tags: function, api, google-sheets, import

I am wanting to use an api to import sunrise and sunset times into a google sheet.
I found this api: https://sunrise-sunset.org/api

I am new to using functions and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how exactly to get my desired results.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your provided URL, it seems that the result values are returned as a JSON data. In this case, when Google Apps Script is used, the JSON data can be easily parsed. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&formatted=0")` to a cell. By this, the script is run and the result value is obtained.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const obj = JSON.parse(res);
  const values = ["sunrise", "sunset"].map(e => [e, new Date(obj.results[e])]);
  return values;
}
```

- In this sample script, the date string is parsed as the date object. So, please include `formatted=0` to the query parameter of the endpoint like `https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&formatted=0`. When this query parameter is used, it seems that the date string is returned as `ISO 8601`. So, I used this.

#### Testing:

When this script is tested, the following result is obtained. In this case, the result value is put as the date object.

[image]

#### Note:

- When you put `=SAMPLE("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&formatted=0")` to a cell, an error occurs, please reopen Spreadsheet and test it again.
- From `I am new to using functions and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how exactly to get my desired results.`, this is a simple sample script for explaining the script. So please modify this sample script for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Sunset and sunrise times API](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)